# Porque a cor de fundo do meu Frame não se altera durante a execução da minha aplicação em Tkinter, mesmo com a definição do parâmetro bg?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *

class Teste(object):
    def __init__(self):
        mestre = Tk()
        mestre.title("Aplicação de teste")
        mestre.geometry("400x400")
        mestre.resizable(False, False)

        #Frames
        self.frame1 = Frame(mestre, bg = "red")
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2 = Frame(mestre, bg = "blue")
        self.frame2.pack()

        mestre.mainloop()
Teste()
```

Por que, mesmo definindo os argumentos "red" e "blue", respectivamente, ao parâmetro de background de self.frame1 e self.frame2, a execução do programa me retorna uma tela com a cor de fundo cinza?
Não era para existir uma tela dividida ao meio, cada metade com uma cor?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

é que quando você cria um Frame, por padrão o Width e o Height dele é 0, logo eles estão vermelhos e azuis.

> height=
>
> > Default is 0. (height/Height)
>
> width=
>
> > Default value is 0. (width/Width)

Logo, a forma correta de criar os seus Frames é a seguinte:

```
#Frames
self.frame1 = Frame(mestre, bg = "red", height=200, width=400)
self.frame2 = Frame(mestre, bg = "blue", height=200, width=400)
```

tem um site muito bom que ajuda na hora de procurar referências para o tkinter chamado Effbot.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook

Comment: Caro, muito obrigado pela resposta!O pior de tudo é que estudei bastante usando esse mesmo site que você indicou e mesmo assim não tinha me ligado nesse padrão de width e height.